# can we save a tokenizer to preprocess raw text in savedmodel?

Tags: tensorflow, deployment, tokenize

I am facing an issue currently, regarding the preprocessing of an input with the SavedModel format.
I am using Transformers model which are using subword/BPE encoder. I can save my model into a savedModel format but I do not know how to add the preprocessing part (the tokenizer) into the savedModel as well.
For instance, "custom" tokenizer such as the hugginface, or the tensorflow tokenizer https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/SubwordTextEncoder .
I haven't found any documentation about SavedModel with preprocessing for NLP. Is that possible in TF 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can't save that into the model. You have to preprocess every time. The word encoder is also given by HugginFace. You can train your own word encoder and save it separately or create a joint model and then, save all the params for the model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by create a joint model ?

Comment: I mean combine the encoder of words and transformer model together. But, I haven't seen that happening in many of the official implementations. So, I think you should stick with just exporting the word encoder separately.